# How to avoid timeout in go test after 10m

Tags: go, go-testing

I'm currently running a suite of tests in Go using the `go test ./...` command. This suite contains multiple test functions, and the execution time exceeds 10 minutes. Unfortunately, the go test command is triggering a timeout error after the 10-minute mark.

I want to avoid using the `--timeout` flag to set a custom timeout value because I'm actively adding more test cases, and the required timeout value may change over time.

Is there a way to entirely disable the timeout feature in the `go test` command, or can it be set to an unlimited value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `0` for the timeout allows the tests to run forever:

```
go test -timeout 0
```

This is documented at [go command: Testing flags](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags):

> ```
>   -timeout d
>       If a test binary runs longer than duration d, panic.
>       If d is 0, the timeout is disabled.
>       The default is 10 minutes (10m).
> ```